# From where can I import Clojure's IPersistentCollection protocol

Tags: clojure

I've currently tried clojure.lang and clojure.core.

I've Googled around, too. But I can't find where it's defined.

Answer (score 6):

It's an Interface, and [is in fact in `clojure.lang`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/IPersistentCollection.java).

Answer (score 3):

There you go:

```
(ns example-ns
  (:import (clojure.lang IPersistentCollection)))
```